# Qt app with OpenGL VBO and shaders produces no output

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl, vbo

I'm trying to get something up on my screen using some code I took directly from a Qt OpenGL example.  However, I can't get anything to show up on my screen.  All the GL functions seem to return correct values and the error log doesn't show any problems.  What's the best way to debug a VBO/shader that's not working at all?

This is my shader code:

```
QGLShaderProgram* ShaderFactory::buildFlatShader(QObject *parent)
{

    string vertSource = string("in vec3 vertex;\n" \
                               "in vec2 a_texcoord;\n" \
                               "uniform mat4 objToWorld;\n" \
                               "uniform mat4 cameraPV;\n" \
                               "void main() {\n" \
                               "  gl_Position = cameraPV * objToWorld * vec4(vertex,1.0);\n" \
                               "  gl_FrontColor = vec4(a_texcoord.x, 1, 0, 1);\n" \
                               "}\n");

    string fragSource = string("void main() {\n" \
                               "  gl_FragColor = gl_Color;\n" \
                               "}\n");

    QGLShader* vertShader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Vertex);
    vertShader->compileSourceCode(vertSource.c_str());

    QGLShader* fragShader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment);
    fragShader->compileSourceCode(fragSource.c_str());

    QGLShaderProgram* program = new QGLShaderProgram(parent);
    program->addShader(vertShader);
    program->addShader(fragShader);

    program->link();

    cout << program->log().toStdString() << endl;
    cout << "Log end--" << endl;

    return program;
}

QGLShaderProgram* ShaderFactory::buildShader(QObject *parent)
{
    string vertSource = string("in vec3 vertex;\n" \
                               "in vec3 normal;\n" \
                               "in vec4 color;\n" \
                               "varying vec3 worldNormal;\n" \
                               "varying vec3 worldPos;\n" \
                               "uniform vec3 cameraPos;\n" \
                               "uniform mat4 objToWorld;\n" \
                               "uniform mat4 cameraV;\n" \
                               "uniform mat4 cameraP;\n" \
                               "uniform mat4 cameraPV;\n" \
                               "void main() {\n" \
                               "  gl_Position = cameraPV * objToWorld * vec4(vertex,1.0);\n" \
                               "  gl_FrontColor = color;\n" \
                               "  gl_BackColor = color;\n" \
                               "  worldPos = vertex;\n" \
                               "  worldNormal = normal;\n" \
                               "}\n");

    string fragSource = string("varying vec3 worldNormal;\n" \
                               "varying vec3 worldPos;\n" \
                               "uniform vec3 cameraPos;\n" \
                               "uniform vec3 lightDir;\n" \
                               "uniform vec4 singleColor;\n" \
                               "uniform float isSingleColor;\n" \
                               "void main() {\n" \
                               "    vec3 L = lightDir;\n" \
                               "    vec3 V = normalize(cameraPos - worldPos);\n" \
                               "    vec3 N = normalize(worldNormal);\n" \
                               "    vec3 H = normalize(L+V);\n" \
                               "    vec4 color = isSingleColor*singleColor + (1.0-isSingleColor)*gl_Color;\n" \
                               "    //vec4 color = gl_Color;\n" \
                               "    float amb = .4;\n" \
                               "    vec4 ambient = color * amb;\n" \
                               "    vec4 diffuse = color * (1.0 - amb) * max(dot(L, N), 0.0);\n" \
                               "    vec4 specular = vec4(0);\n" \
                               "    gl_FragColor = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular);\n" \
                               "}\n");

    QGLShader* vertShader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Vertex);
    vertShader->compileSourceCode(vertSource.c_str());

    QGLShader* fragShader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment);
    fragShader->compileSourceCode(fragSource.c_str());

    QGLShaderProgram* program = new QGLShaderProgram(parent);
    program->addShader(vertShader);
    program->addShader(fragShader);

    return program;
}
```

This is my OpenGL code

```
PanelGL::PanelGL() : QGLWidget(PanelGL::defaultFormat())
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
    _validShaders = false;

    camera = new Camera();

    if (mainGrid == NULL) {
        int range[] = {-10,10};
        int numSegments = range[1]-range[0]+1;
        QVector<LineSegment> segments(numSegments);
        for (int i = 0; i < numSegments; i++) {
            segments[i].p1 = Point3(i, 0, 10);
            segments[i].p2 = Point3(i, 0, -10);
            segments[i].r = 0.4f;
            segments[i].g = 0.4f;
            segments[i].b = 0.4f;
        }
        mainGrid = new LineRenderer(segments, 2);
    }
}

QGLFormat PanelGL::defaultFormat()
{
    QGLFormat format;
    //format.setVersion(3,2);
    //format.setProfile(QGLFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    return format;
}

bool glewInitialized = false;

void PanelGL::initializeGL()
{
    if (!glewInitialized) {
        GLenum err = glewInit();
        if (GLEW_OK != err)
        {
            /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
            cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << endl;
        }
    }
}

void PanelGL::paintGL()
{   
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if (!_validShaders) {
        _dummyShader = ShaderFactory::buildShader(this);
        _flatShader = ShaderFactory::buildFlatShader(this);
        _validShaders = true;
    }

    // render the grid
    mainGrid->render(this);

    //glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void PanelGL::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
}

LineRenderer::LineRenderer(QVector<LineSegment> segments, float lineWidth)
{
    _validVBOs = FALSE;
    //_segments = segments;
    _lineWidth = lineWidth;
}

struct VertexData
{
    Vector3 position;
    Vector2 texCoord;
};

void LineRenderer::render(PanelGL* panel)
{
    if (!_validVBOs) {
        glGenBuffers(2, _vboIds);

        _validVBOs = TRUE;
    }

    loadVBOs(panel);

    Camera* camera = panel->camera;
    QMatrix4x4 cameraViewM = Camera::getViewMatrix(camera,panel->width(),panel->height());
    QMatrix4x4 cameraProjM = Camera::getProjMatrix(camera,panel->width(),panel->height());
    QMatrix4x4 cameraProjViewM = cameraProjM * cameraViewM;
    QMatrix4x4 objToWorld;

    QGLShaderProgram* flatShader = panel->getFlatShader();

    glLineWidth(_lineWidth);
    flatShader->bind();
    int objToWorldLoc = flatShader->attributeLocation("objToWorld");
    flatShader->setUniformValue(objToWorldLoc, objToWorld);
    int cameraPVLoc = flatShader->attributeLocation("cameraPV");
    flatShader->setUniformValue(cameraPVLoc, cameraProjViewM);
    int overrideStrengthLoc = flatShader->attributeLocation("overrideStrength");
    flatShader->setUniformValue(overrideStrengthLoc, 0.0f);

    // Tell OpenGL which VBOs to use
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboIds[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboIds[1]);
    // Offset for position
    int offset = 0;
    // Tell OpenGL programmable pipeline how to locate vertex position data
    int vertexLocation = flatShader->attributeLocation("vertex");
    flatShader->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const void *)offset);
    // Offset for texture coordinate
    offset += sizeof(QVector3D);
    // Tell OpenGL programmable pipeline how to locate vertex texture coordinate data
    int texcoordLocation = flatShader->attributeLocation("a_texcoord");
    flatShader->enableAttributeArray(texcoordLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const void *)offset);
    // Draw cube geometry using indices from VBO 1
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 34, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    //drawSegments.call
    flatShader->release();
}

void LineRenderer::loadVBOs(PanelGL* panel)
{
    VertexData vertices[] = {
            // Vertex data for face 0
            {QVector3D(-1.0, -1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.0, 0.0)},  // v0
            {QVector3D( 1.0, -1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 0.0)}, // v1
            {QVector3D(-1.0,  1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.0, 0.5)},  // v2
            {QVector3D( 1.0,  1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 0.5)}, // v3
            // Vertex data for face 1
            {QVector3D( 1.0, -1.0,  1.0), QVector2D( 0.0, 0.5)}, // v4
            {QVector3D( 1.0, -1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 0.5)}, // v5
            {QVector3D( 1.0,  1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.0, 1.0)},  // v6
            {QVector3D( 1.0,  1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 1.0)}, // v7
            // Vertex data for face 2
            {QVector3D( 1.0, -1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 0.5)}, // v8
            {QVector3D(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(1.0, 0.5)},  // v9
            {QVector3D( 1.0,  1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 1.0)}, // v10
            {QVector3D(-1.0,  1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(1.0, 1.0)},  // v11
            // Vertex data for face 3
            {QVector3D(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 0.0)}, // v12
            {QVector3D(-1.0, -1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(1.0, 0.0)},  // v13
            {QVector3D(-1.0,  1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 0.5)}, // v14
            {QVector3D(-1.0,  1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(1.0, 0.5)},  // v15
            // Vertex data for face 4
            {QVector3D(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 0.0)}, // v16
            {QVector3D( 1.0, -1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 0.0)}, // v17
            {QVector3D(-1.0, -1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 0.5)}, // v18
            {QVector3D( 1.0, -1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 0.5)}, // v19
            // Vertex data for face 5
            {QVector3D(-1.0,  1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 0.5)}, // v20
            {QVector3D( 1.0,  1.0,  1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 0.5)}, // v21
            {QVector3D(-1.0,  1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.33, 1.0)}, // v22
            {QVector3D( 1.0,  1.0, -1.0), QVector2D(0.66, 1.0)}  // v23
        };
        // Indices for drawing cube faces using triangle strips.
        // Triangle strips can be connected by duplicating indices
        // between the strips. If connecting strips have opposite
        // vertex order then last index of the first strip and first
        // index of the second strip needs to be duplicated. If
        // connecting strips have same vertex order then only last
        // index of the first strip needs to be duplicated.
        GLushort indices[] = {
             0,  1,  2,  3,  3,     // Face 0 - triangle strip ( v0,  v1,  v2,  v3)
             4,  4,  5,  6,  7,  7, // Face 1 - triangle strip ( v4,  v5,  v6,  v7)
             8,  8,  9, 10, 11, 11, // Face 2 - triangle strip ( v8,  v9, v10, v11)
            12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, // Face 3 - triangle strip (v12, v13, v14, v15)
            16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, // Face 4 - triangle strip (v16, v17, v18, v19)
            20, 20, 21, 22, 23      // Face 5 - triangle strip (v20, v21, v22, v23)
        };
        // Transfer vertex data to VBO 0
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboIds[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * sizeof(VertexData), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Transfer index data to VBO 1
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboIds[1]);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 34 * sizeof(GLushort), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the XYZ components of QVector3D are tightly packed?  I recommend doing a glGetBufferSubData and having a look at exactly what you're uploading, or just test the same numbers with pure float C arrays.

Comment: You've also told your vertex pointers to expect floats, but QVector3D/2D stores qreal type which on a PC platform typedefs to double.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with just a really simple fragment shader (no vertex shader) like:

```
void main() 
{
    /* Color the fragment red */
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```